# GCP-Audit Cloud Custodian

Tags: google-cloud-platform, cloudcustodian

I've been trying out cloud custodian and looking at this article trying the simplest thing using gcp-audit (all services/APIs needed are enabled)

```
policies:
  - name: gcp-uniform-access-storage-remediation
    resource: gcp.bucket
    mode:
      type: gcp-audit
      methods:
        - storage.buckets.create
        - storage.buckets.update
    filters:
      - type: value
        key: iamConfiguration.uniformBucketLevelAccess.enabled
        value: false
    actions:
      - type: set-uniform-access
```

https://medium.com/google-cloud/compliance-as-code-and-auto-remediation-on-google-cloud-with-cloud-custodian-e488ca6ab06c

Running the policy seems like but when adding the function of gcp-audit it seems to fail and triggering the cloud function manually it just shows crash with no other information, has anyone had any similar issue? Appreciate any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems deleting the log sink router and re-deploy solves the issue for me